# CakePHP and Bootstrap form integration

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

I have set up my CakePHP installation with Bootstrap 3 using [BoostCake](http://slywalker.github.io/cakephp-plugin-boost_cake/).

Now, what I would like would be to create a view like the following Bootstrap sign in example:
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/

How do I integrate this bootstrap layout using the Formhelper in CakePHP?

For example: In regular CakePHP I would do the following to create a login button:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Login', array('type' => 'submit')) ?>
```

However that won't produce the nice blue login button, so instead I can do this:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
<?php echo $this->Form->end() ?>
```

So if I have a login text field:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('User.username'); ?>
```

How can I transform that to use the textbox visual in the signin example while still using the formhelper?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you still including your old CSS file? I'd say it might have something to do with that.

Comment: The plugin does not modify the layout HTML. You need to edit `default.ctp` and your view files to use cake's grid system.

Comment: I realized that my question was more about how to actually use bootstrap and not so much about setting it up. Thank you for the feedback, I have edited my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the classes in the options array. For instance, your submit method could change to:

```
<?php
   echo $this->Form->submit('Sign In',array(
                              'class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block',
                              'div' => false));
?>
```

The `input` method also allows for the options array for your login text field.